# Is there a "Post deserialization hook"?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Using mongo C# driver, can I tap into the deserialization process, so that for every deserialized object of type `Foo`, I can immediately manipulate the object, before it is returned to the caller?

Simplified example:

```
class Foo
{
    [BsonIgnore]
    public bool IsChanged {get;set;}

    ...
}

...

var foo = Collection.FindOneByIdAs<Foo>(id);
foo.IsChanged; // true
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can implement ISupportInitialize from the .NET framework and we'll invoke it appropriately. See our documentation here: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/#implementing-isupportinitialize.

Comment: Nice. It is a bit difficult, because then I would have to reference some dependencies in `Foo` (I want to avoid static calls in `EndInit`).

Comment: ISupportInitialize is not part of the driver. It is part of the BCL. You shouldn't need to reference any extra assemblies. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isupportinitialize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I know. But if `Foo` implements it, it would have to do something more complex than changing `IsChanged`. It would call `IBar.DoSomething()`, etc.. I would rather have another type (like `FooSerializer`) act on the `Foo` instance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it with your custom Foo Serializer

```
public class FooSerialzer : BsonBaseSerializer
{
    private static readonly IBsonSerializer Serializer;

    static FooSerialzer()
    {
        var classMap = BsonClassMap.LookupClassMap(typeof(Foo));
        var serializerType = Type.GetType("MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer, MongoDB.Bson", true);
        Serializer = (IBsonSerializer)Activator.CreateInstance(serializerType, classMap);
    }

    public override object Deserialize(BsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
    {
        var document = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(bsonReader);
        var foo = (Foo)Serializer.Deserialize(BsonReader.Create(document), typeof(Foo), options);

        // do your customization for foo here
        return foo;
    }

    public override void Serialize(BsonWriter bsonWriter, Type nominalType, object value, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
    {
        var foo = (Foo) value;
        foo.Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString();

        var document = new BsonDocument();
        Serializer.Serialize(BsonWriter.Create(document), nominalType, value, options);

        BsonSerializer.Serialize(bsonWriter, document);
    }
}
```

Just remember to register this in your app startup

```
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(typeof(Foo), new FooSerialzer());
```

In this scenario you dont have to serialize and deserialize for complex objects.

Comment: then you would have to implement the whole serialization (of a complex object) yourself.

Comment: @I3arnon, I came up with a new solution